# Compiler exhaust check for list of case objects inheriting from sealed trait

Tags: scala

I have the following code (simplified):

```
sealed trait Status {
    def code: String
}

object Status {
    final case object Failed extends Status {
        val code: String = "failed"
    }

    final case object Succeeded extends Status {
        val code: String = "succeeded"
    }

    val allStatuses = List(Failed, Succeded)
}
```

Is there a smart way to ensure the `allStatuses` list contains all possible types of `Status`, or an alternative way to have an iterable, exhaustive collection of them?

The reason is I want to be able to convert a `String` into an `Option[Status]` by matching on the `code` of each object or returning `None` if it matches none of them. And I want the code to be safe in case I add more possible statuses in the future.

Comment: wouldn't it be better solution for you to use `Enumaration`?
then just do `pattern matching`? or iterate thru `Enumaration.values`?

Comment: @Bublik `Enumeration` doesn't have exhaustiveness checking in `match`, so it's best to avoid using it completely. Also it doesn't allow to make arbitraty fields and methods in the values (like `Status.code` in the OP).

Comment: @Kolmar it is not true:
`object Example extends Enumeration {
  case class FieldVal(code: String) extends Val(nextId)
  type Example = FieldVal
  val FAILED = FieldValue("failed") }`

you can add fields and methods

Answer (score 0):

You can get them with scala reflection. First you'd need to import `scala-reflect` library:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
```

Then you have to traverse all modules that extend the sealed class with the help of `knownDirectSubclasses`:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe
import reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import reflect.runtime.universe._

def knownSubmodules[T : TypeTag]: List[T] = {
  def run(symbol: universe.Symbol): List[T] = {
    if (symbol.isModuleClass) {
      val moduleMirror = currentMirror.reflectModule(symbol.asClass.module.asModule)
      List(moduleMirror.instance.asInstanceOf[T])
    }
    else if (symbol.isClass && symbol.asClass.isSealed) {
      symbol.asClass.knownDirectSubclasses.toList.flatMap(run)
    }
    else Nil
  }

  run(symbolOf[T])
}
```

So, for the following inheritance structure:

```
sealed trait Base1

case object Foo1 extends Base1

case object Bar1 extends Base1

sealed trait Base2 extends Base1

case object Foo2 extends Base2

case object Bar2 extends Base2
```

It will return all 4 objects:

```
scala> knownSubmodules[Base1]

res1: List[Base1] = List(Bar1, Bar2, Foo2, Foo1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
object Status extends Enumeration {

  case class FieldVal(code: String) extends Val(nextId)

  type Status = FieldVal

  val FAILED = FieldVal("Failed")
  val SUCCEEDED = FieldVal("Succeeded")

  def fromString(value: String): Status = {
    values.find(v => v.asInstanceOf[Status].code.equals(value))
      .map(_.asInstanceOf[Status])
      .getOrElse(FAILED)
  }
}
```